# Неоднозначное состояние объекта

Tags: javascript

При выполнении

```
console.log(obj)
```

, где obj - некоторый объект, выдается следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, сразу показывается, что объект содержит вложенный объект todos и свойство bubus со значением 0.
При этом при раскрытии этого элемента свойство bubus уже равно 10.
При попытке выполнить

```
 console.log(obj.todos)
```

вообще выдается UNDEFINED. Как это может быть?

Answer (score 0):

Объекты меняются во времени.

В лог попадает ссылка на объект.

Можно пользоваться "неизменяемыми объектами".

Можно превращать объект в json при логировании.